# How does the InsideTessFactor affect points of a triangle in a DirectX11 domain shader?

Tags: directx, directx11, tessellation, hull-shaders, domain-shaders

[image]

[I found this example in this Chinese language document](https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/42550699).

In the image above, I can understand the value of `SV_TessFactor` because for every side of this triangle, there are `4,1,6` line segments respectively. But I don't understand how `InsideTessFactor` is 5.

There are 12 points and 12 line segments inside the triangle. It seems to me that 12 is not relevant to 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can understand this as a continuation of the two preceding diagrams in the document you linked:

[image: Tessellation Sequence]

For an inside tesselation factor **n**, we first imagine that each of the sides of the outside triangle have been subdivided into **n** segments.

Then we draw a perpendicular up from each of the newly-added vertices. Where the two perpendiculars closest to a corner intersect, we place the corners of our next inner triangle (blue).

The other perpendiculars add vertices where they cross this triangle's sides. That means that for a triangle tessellated by a factor of **n**, this inner triangle has **n - 2** segments along each side.

Then we repeat to make a nested inner triangle (or point), until we have no more vertices in the middle of a subdivided edge to draw perpendiculars from.

So when the inside tessellation factor is 5, that first inner triangle in blue has **5 - 2 = 3** segments along each side.

You'll note this inner 3-segment triangle for the 5 case in my diagram matches the 3-segment inner triangle in your question. All that differs are the number of segments on the outer triangle's sides, controlled by the other tessellation factors.

Comment: Thank you so much,DMGregory,this perfectly solved my question.The illustrations here are very informative.